# Using Microsoft Planner API, how to add comments and attachments to Planner Tasks

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Im currently trying to make a quick planner interface using C#, basically trying to move hundreds of Trello boards over to planner.

Ive found the examples to create boards, buckets, tasks etc

An example on how to add task is below

```
var createdTask = await _graphClient.Planner.Tasks.Request().AddAsync(
    new PlannerTask
        {
            DueDateTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
            Title = "Do the dishes",
            Details = new PlannerTaskDetails
            {
                Description = "Do the dishes that are remaining in the sink"
            },
            Assignments = assignments,
            PlanId = planId,
            BucketId = bucketId,
        }
    );
```

What I cant find however is how to add comments and attachments, I'm probs missing something really obvious but how do I add them lol

Thanks